# How to export to pdf without scrollbars in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

How can we print or export a PDF of a lengthy matrix or table visual without displaying a scrollbar? I've expanded the visual to its full size and increased the page length, but the scrollbar still appears. Is there any solution within paginated reports to address this?

I've tried searching for it but couldn't find any the information.